# Iterate with keys in JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have problem with for loop in JSONObject. I try to modify element "name".
I know all keys for objects.
I have list with Strings: `["person 1", "data", "moreInfo", "name", "John"];
I know that they are objects. Data inside person 1, moreInfo in data etc...

I can change it like that:

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject(jsonFile);
js = js.getJSONObject("person 1").getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("moreInfo");
js.put("name","secName");
```

It is okay but I dont know how much elements I will have in list.
Maybe: `["person 1" ....... "moreInfo", "name", "John"];`
I try to use for loop but I cant make it with that, it is possible to iterate to  result like that: `getJSONObject("moreInfo")`?

```
{
    "Person 1": -firstWord in list {
        "data": {
            "moreInfo": {
                "name": "John"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of the JSON string?

Comment: Okay, edit first post but it is random data because is generating from file. I have keys and I have to go object with key of index `list.size()-2` and on that object execute put method.

Comment: Side question: Is is possible to get the JSON into a format of `{ "people": [ { "name": "John", "moredata": {"value": "extras"} } ]`

Comment: Get all jsonElements("Person 1", "Person 2") using JsonObject. Loop through them one by one.

Check the jsonelement isJsonObject or isJsonArray. If the above condition satisfies, again get the element and continue iteration until you get a valid value.

JsonObject (com.google.gson)

Will provide you methods with isJsonObject, isJsonArray to validate the json element.

Comment: I can replace it to `[ ]` if it is the best option to modify/remove/add elements to that object.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you have a string array of size n, the first n-1 elements are json paths, and the last one is the new value you want to set

You can do it like this:

```
    String[] paths = new String[] {"person 1","a","b","c","moreInfo", "name", "John"};

    JSONObject root = js;
    JSONObject current = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length - 2; i++) {
        current = current.getJSONObject(paths[i]);
    }
    current.put(paths[paths.length - 2], paths[paths.length - 1]);
```

I skip the correctness check here. But you may want to add code to check whether the key exists in each step.

Comment: There shouldn't be `current = current.getJSONObject(paths[i]);`?

Comment: You are right, typo fixed. It should be ''current'' instead of ''root'' in the loop